# javascript - cannot get 'onChange' to work within IE under <select> tag

Tags: javascript

```
<form name="form1">
Currency:<br><select name="currency" onchange='select()'>
      <option name ='usd'>USD</option>
      <option>Euro</option>
      <option name ='won'>Won</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I cannot get the onChange function to execute, but it works fine in FF, opera, and chrome ??

anyone know why?

Comment: Using the *change* event with select elements requires careful consideration and design. If keyboard navigation is being used, some browsers (e.g. IE) will fire a change event each time the cursor key is pressed to select a new option. In particular, never use onchange for navigation.

Comment: Since 1995 I have never had any issues with onchange on a select. I do not see where you would have issues with that.

Comment: @mplungian: was there an onchange handler for selects back in 1995? Javascript (Livescript) saw its first light in december 1995 :~)

Comment: That is when I started using it :) NS2 (December 1995) and IE3.02

Comment: @Shawn - would be nice if you returned and had a look at the code we wrote

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript">
function TextValue(TestValue)
{
document.f2.samptext.value=TestValue;           
}
</script>
<form name="f2">
<select name="select" onchange="TextValue(this.value)">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="samptext" id="samptext" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is below. But Jquery is needed for this

```
<script language="javascript">
function TextValue()
{
var value =  $('#selectThis').val();          
}
</script>
<form name="f2">
<select name="select" onchange="TextValue() id="selectThis">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="samptext" id="samptext" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the select() function which is what is failing.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fXacE/

Note that the script I suggest needs neither name nor id to work but if you DO use document.getElementById you MUST have an ID since in 2011, only IE will overload getElementById to also get a named element

Also I would like to point out some wrong syntax - there is no name on options. Also be consistent on quotes

```js
var currenCurrency = "";

function setCurrency(sel) {
  currentCurrency = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; // or sel.value
  console.log(currentCurrency);
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  Currency:<br>
  <select name="currency" id="currency" onchange="setCurrency(this)">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="usd">USD</option>
    <option value="euro">Euro</option>
    <option value="won">Won</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

If you do NOT want inline event handlers, then in plain JS you can use

```
var currentCurrency="";
window.onload=function() { // addEventListener is better but not supported by IE<v10
  document.getElementById("currency").onchange=function() {
    currentCurrency=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; // or sel.value
  }
  document.getElementById("currency").onchange(); // set the current value
}
```

***jQuery***

`$("#currency option:selected").text()`

and

`$("#currency option:selected").val()` which is the same as `$("#currency").val()`

Comment: The presence or absence of a name attribute on option elements is irrelevant to whether a change event is dispatched or not.

Comment: However the presence does allude to the fact that there are other issues with the user's syntax. Also the use of a reserved word as function name. My code works as it stands. OP's original code would never trigger USD unless you first changed one option. Also there was no value on the Euro. I would need to see the rest of the code to see why IE was unhappy

Comment: mplungjan - *select* is not a reserved word in ECMAScript, nor does it have any special meaning in javascript. You could also complain about a lack of an *action* attribute of the form but that is irrelevant here too. You are correct about the USD option and very probably correct that the error is likely in the *select()* function.

Comment: You honour, the statement of the usage of select was pertaining to the OP's state of mind when writing the code ;)

Comment: Downvoting without comments is my #1 pet hate here.

Answer (score 0):

If the function assigned to onchange isn't giving expected results in IE, it is likely a result of the listener failing to execute rather than the event not being dispatched. Replace the listener with a simple function to see if works.

e.g.

```
<form name="form1">
  Currency:<br>
  <select name="currency" onchange='this.form.inp0.value = this.value'>
    <option value='usd'>USD</option>
    <option value="euro">Euro</option>
    <option value='kpw'>Won</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="inp0">
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm, I believe I already gave a working example of a select and the onchange handler... And how will you select USD?